# Creating a PCB mount RJ45 male plug

Tags: pcb, rj45

I am wondering on how one could build a male RJ45 connector with PCB Mount. I searched and, as I expected, I did not found any existant connector like this. However, I found this interresting item :
[image: Tool]

The "core" of the RJ45 plug seems to be a PCB piece, and it looks inserted into an empty RJ45 connector.

Do somebody know how something like this could be designed ?

Have you ever heard about an existing male RJ45 connector with PCB Mount ?

Regarding the background of the problem, I design circuitry on Flexible PCB and I would like to  avoid using regular RJ45 cable to minimize the size of the design.

Comment: I guess there are spring contacts on the pcb and it is just inserted instead wires.

Comment: Interesting. I suspect that if your PCB is thin enough (0.4 mm and such), you can just insert it into a normal connector and "crimp" it. Definitely not reliable though, so I hope you find something that's designed for this.

Comment: The RJ45 depends on the little guides of the plug to help keep the socket contacts apart. An extra thick layer of solder resist might help... I can imagine this working for some sockets but not reliably in all.

Comment: Would a through-hole part be OK for your FPC design? I did something a while back on a design that used one on a regular PCB and while I didn't do the hardware can find out the part they used.

Comment: A through-hole part would be OK. Can you provide me more details about that ?

Answer (score 8):

Use Metz Connect part [AJP92A8813](https://www.metz-connect.com/us/products/ajp92a8813)

Its designed for this

[image: photo]

Comment: This is more of a shopping list than an answer.   Sooner or later, that part will be discontinued and this answer would be useless.

Comment: @OskarSkog Not so. What you're highlighting is a major flaw on this forum and you're falling into the same trap. Yes the specific part may be discontinued tomorrow, but the general concept of a male solder able Ethernet connector similar to this one will always remain useful. Anyone reading this in decades to come will know what generic type of component to search for...

Comment: @PaulUszak Stack Exchange is not a forum. However you could edit the post to make it more generic, whilst linking to this part.

Comment: @PaulUszak:  What's the generic term to search for?  The "answer" doesn't seem to include that.

Comment: @OskarSkog I was going to post a condescending and pithy comeback, but couldn't think of one.

Answer (score 3):

This answers the question "how would something like that be designed", but is not much use for solving your current problem, the difference to cost-effectiveness being at least 10 000 units (custom molding)

An Alibaba listing, https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/8p8c-rj45-toolless-cat6-Modular-Connectors_60546446580.html has suprisingly clear pictures of the construction of such a plug. I've included the relevant detail:

[image: Construction of a PCB-8P8C plug]

As you can see, the plug has curled spring contacts and the wire socket does not have the usual wire guides. The plug is also lacking the widened part of the cable guide and the strain relief, that give the mechanical strength for a standard network plug.

Now, if someone were to find a source for such plugs, I'd be very interested. So far, I've had not much luck.

Answer (score -2):

wild guess here but perhaps you can use the metal case from [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Rj45-Cat6-shielding-Networking-Connectors-with-modem-Cable-The-network-adapter/32374517455.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.48.Ubr02c&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_0,searchweb201602_3_10037_10034_507_10032_508_10020_10017_10005_10006_10021_10022_10018_10019,searchweb201603_9&btsid=2f2da83c-67dc-4921-842e-7eb8a0faaab7) connector to solder it to your pcb and connect the wires as needed.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, James. There are a few problems with your answer: (1) The main content is in a link which, if it dies, renders your answer useless in future. You should at least include the photo of the part. (2) That's not designed to be soldered to a PCB. (3) The OP stated that he is using a flexible PCB. (4) The connector is designed for IDC crimp connection to a proper telephone cable. (5) Please capitalise the first letter of your sentences if you wish to be taken seriously. Sorry.